# Execute a sql query inside IF() function

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.3

Wherever I find an example of `IF ()` function I only see something like below.

```
SELECT IF(500<1000, "YES", "NO");
+---------------------------+
| IF(500<1000, "YES", "NO") |
+---------------------------+
| YES                       |
+---------------------------+
```

But can I do something like below i.e executing a query?

```
IF(500<1000, CREATE DATABASE test1; , CREATE DATABASE test2;);
```

One way is to using prepared statements. But I want to directly execute the query inside it.

Comment: SELECT IF (500<1000, 1, 0)

Comment: Actually I need to execute sql query. Not any string or integer.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You need to use a statement block like `CASE`, not a function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a little bit. And probably post the answer.

Comment: @SkyRar There is an `IF()` function and `IF..THEN..ELSE..END IF;` statements. You can call another statements from the IF statement not from the IF() function.

Comment: @Kondybas I am aware of that. But I need IF() function for some reason.

Comment: Some reason? If you know there is an If statement, what's the reason for not using it?

Comment: "But I need IF() function for some reason" , - please show the exact reason. This looks like something that should be in application code.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about Stored Programs.  Write a Procedure that uses `IF` *statements*, not *functions*, to conditionally perform SQL statements.

Then invoke the Stored Procedure with a `CALL` statement.